# Is there a way to set required attribute on text_field_tag?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

In `text_field` one can do the following to set the `required` attribute.

> < %= f.text_field :street, :required => true % >
>
> < input id="recipe_name" name="recipe_name" type="text" required >

However, with `text_field_tag`, if I do the same the output html sets the value attribute instead, which is not correct.

> < %= text_field_tag :street, :required => true % >

output:

> < input id="recipe_name" name="recipe_name" type="text" value="{:required=>true}" >

Is `required` not supported in `text_field_tag`?  What is a good way to work around it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try: [text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag)

```
<%= text_field_tag :street, nil, :required => true %>
```

When you provide `options` to the helper, you have to pass the value for `value` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

[Text field tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag)

Try this:

```
<%= text_field_tag :street, '', :required => true %>
```