# Ruby on Rails- Making input required for a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make this input in my search required to start a search. I tried :validate if there is input but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
<%= text_field_tag "location", params[:location], :placeholder => 'City, zipcode, or address' %>
```

Comment: Does it a model attribute, please elaborate your problem

Comment: No, I am just trying to make sure that there is just something typed into that field.

Comment: I am not exactly get what you want but as per my understanding you don't have `location` attribute in your model if that is correct then try like this: add `attr_accessor :location` and `validate :location, presence: true`

Comment: You are asking how to make the text field be required? Question has already been asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487514/is-there-a-way-to-set-required-attribute-on-text-field-tag

Comment: @anusha I do have the location attribute in my model. I tried '<%= text_field_tag "location", params[:location], :placeholder => 'City, zipcode, or address', :location, nil, :required => true %>' but I got an error. I simply want the user to have to enter something in the field before they can press search. If they press search and it is not entered, I'd prefer to have some text in that field saying that filling in that field is required.

Comment: @user3810969 had u tried `sikendar singh` solution that to add validations and which error you are getting

Comment: Looks like your asking for client side validation ? Like, an input is required for search to perform ? If thats the cases, user query.validate plugin or use html5 validation :)

Answer (score 1):

change the syntax

```
<%= text_field_tag "location", "#{params[:location]}", :placeholder => 'City, zipcode, or address' {:required => true} %>
```

and add this to your model

```
validates :location, presence: true
```

Answer (score 0):

In whatever model the location belongs to, try adding this syntax:

```
class whatever < ActiveRecord::Base    
  validates :location, presence: true
end
```

make sure that location is part of attar_accessible in your model.